# Switching teams on being hit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a hide and seek game with my friends and i wanna make it so when we're playing a tag mode. Whenever the seeker hits the hider, the seeker becomes a hider and the hider a seeker. I already have the 2 teams set up `Hiders` and `Seekers`

Comment: You could try tracking the `minecraft:damage_taken` stat.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm not that good at the command stuff

Answer (score 3):

You could fairly comfortably use [custom advancements](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancement/JSON_format) in a datapack to do this.

You have one advancement that checks for a hiding player being hit by a seeking player, then grants a reward function that makes them switch teams and resets the advancement to be used again.

> **IMPORTANT:** Due to how minecraft advancements work, we need to delay the swapping of teams to the next tick, because otherwise one of the advancements will run first, run its corresponding function and the other advancement will not have its conditions met anymore.

`foo/advancements/hit_by_seeker.json`

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "requirement": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:entity_hurt_player",
      "conditions": {
        "player": {
          "team": "Hiders"
        },
        "damage": {
          "source_entity": {
            "type": "player",
            "team": "Seekers"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "rewards": {
    "function": "foo:hit_by_seeker"
  }
}
```

`foo/functions/hit_by_seeker.mcfunction`

```
advancement revoke @s only foo:hit_by_seeker
tag @s add Seekers

schedule function foo:swap 1t replace
```

And then another one that checks for the seeker hitting a hider to have the reverse effect:

`foo/advancements/hit_hider.json`

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "requirement": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:player_hurt_entity",
      "conditions": {
        "player": {
          "team": "Seekers"
        },
        "entity": {
          "type": "player",
          "team": "Hiders"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "rewards": {
    "function": "foo:hit_hider"
  }
}
```

`foo/functions/hit_hider.mcfunction`

```
advancement revoke @s only foo:hit_hider
tag @s add Hiders

schedule function foo:swap 1t replace
```

And finally, the function to actually swap the teams.

`foo/functions/swap.mcfunction`

```
team join Hiders @a[tag=Hiders]
team join Seekers @a[tag=Seekers]

tag @a remove Hiders
tag @a remove Seekers
```

Comment: do i just put them in a command block and run it once or do i have to run it multiple times?

Comment: @Rosy-senpai no commandblocks needed for this one - these are 4 different files inside a datapack. In fact, it won't work with just commandblocks, this is explicitly a datapacks answer.

Comment: How do i make these files? Just put it in like a txt file or something? Have never coded like this before

Comment: You need to make a Datapack for this to work. [Here is a tutorial on how to do that](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Creating_a_data_pack). Don't worry, a datapack isn't complicated, it's just a few folders and a text files inside the world. Then you add the above files as text files (in the example `foo` is the namespace, so it goes inside the `data` folder)

Comment: Thank you, ill let you know if i run into any problems

Comment: i dont get what the 'foo' means. I placed the 4 files in a folder called 'hit by hider' inside the 'data' folder inside the 'world' folder.

Comment: @Rosy-senpai the "foo" is just an example namespace name. you can have your own folder names, but they have to be lowercase and cannot have spaces. And you'll need to change `foo` above into `hit_by_hider` (assuming that's the folder name) in all 4 files. Also, make sure you follow the datapack setup tutorial, it is supposed to be `world/datapacks/<your datapack>/data/<namespace>`. and don't forget the .mcmeta file

Comment: I now have '/world/datapacks/hit by hider/data' and then the 4 files (2 '.json' and 2 '.mcmeta' files)

Comment: full file location needs to be: `world/datapacks/hit by hider/data/hit_by_hider/functions/hit_hider.mcfunction`. When you have that and you run `/reload` in chat, the function should show up in the autocomplete when you do `/function hit_by_hider:hit_hider`.

Comment: Wait so where do i put the .json files? in the functions folder too?

Comment: no, they are advancements. that's why I gave you the full path in the first place. instead of inside the `functions` folder they need to be in the `advancements` folder.

Comment: ah okay, ill try that real quick

Comment: is the advancements folder the original advancements folder or do i make another one in the datapacks folder

Comment: also i should probably replace the foo in the .mcfuntion files with data right? Or the whole path where its in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144504/discussion-between-plagiatus-and-rosy-senpai).

Answer (score 2):

Since Teams are annoying to use with commands, I like to use a scoreboard to track the teams, and use the scores to switch teams. Something like a `Team` scorebaord, where 0 is Hider and 1 is Seeker. Then two commands that set  the teams which alawys run.

```
execute as @a if score @s Team matches 0 run team join Hider @s
execute as @a if score @s Team matches 1 run team join Seeker @s
```

Aside from this, we will need a scoreboard to track damage_dealt and damage_taken. We will want to check whenever a Seeker dealt damage, then check for the closest Hider who has taken damage and tag them. We then use the tagged Hider to switch the Seeker's team and itself. With datapacks, it wouldn't be needed to tag them, but since these are commands blocks, it is needed.

First the scoreboards:

```
scoreboard objectives add dmg_dealt stat.damageDealt
scoreboard objectives add dmg_taken stat.damageTaken
```

The logic:

```
execute as @a[scores={Team=1,dmg_dealt=1..}] at @s as @p[scores={Team=0,dmg_taken=1..}] run tag @s add Hit
execute as @a[tag=Hit] as @p[scores={Team=1,dmg_dealt=1..}] run scoreboard players set @s Team 0
execute as @a[tag=Hit] run scoreboard players set @s Team 1
execute as @a[tag=Hit] run tag @s remove Hit
execute as @a run scoreboard players set @s dmg_taken 0
execute as @a run scoreboard players set @s dmg_taken 0
```

This should work with multiple Seekers. These commands are currently untested, so please let me know if something goes wrong!

Comment: so im trying this and the scoreboard already fail. The `stat.damageDealt` doesnt exist, or atleast it gives me an error

Comment: You might need to do the full path. Something along the lines of `minecraft.custom:minecraft.damage_dealt`. You can use the tab function in chat for auto completion and pardon the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is give the seekers strength and when a hider dies turn them into a seeker like:
`scoreboard objectives add isdead deathCount`

`execute as @a if score @s isdead matches 0.. run function namespace:functionname`

And in that function, you set the scoreboard value back to 0 and do whatever stuff you want it to do for the team switching.